# Trying to understanding using Kotlin with Ant

Tags: java, kotlin, ant, ivy

```
<target name="build">
    <delete dir="classes" failonerror="false"/>
    <mkdir dir="classes"/>
    <javac destdir="classes" includeAntRuntime="false" srcdir="src">
        <withKotlin/>
    </javac>
    <jar destfile="hello.jar">
        <fileset dir="classes"/>
    </jar>
</target>
```

[Kotlin Website](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-ant.html)

I am working on integrating Kotlin with my existing Java project (ivy and ant). Currently we use ivy.xml for dependency management and ant for build scripts.

1. If I used IVY, does it make specifying `classpath="${kotlin.lib}/kotlin-ant.jar"` redundant ?
2. I get an error `org/jetbrains/kotlin/ant/antlib.xml` not found in classpath. How to resolve it ?
3. How to add kotlin-ant.jar & and all its dependencies using using Ivy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Ivy is used, then no need for specifying `classpath="${kotlin.lib}/kotlin-ant.jar"`

Regarding 2 & 3.

Create configurations for the Kotlin Dependencies in the ivy.xml

```
<configurations>
    <conf name="kotlin" description="Kotlin Tasks"/>
</configurations>

<dependencies>
    <dependency org="xxxxx" name="kotlin-ant" rev="xxxxx" conf="kotlin->default"/>
</dependencies>
```

In Build.xml, update the configuration.

```
<target name="resolve">
    <ivy:resolve />
    <ivy:cachepath pathid="kotlin.classpath" conf="kotlin"/>
</target>

<target name="build" depends="resolve">
    <typedef resource="org/jetbrains/kotlin/ant/antlib.xml" classpathref="kotlin.classpath"/>
 <kotlinc .....
    </kotlinc>
</target>
```